# Не хватает памяти

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, сервер, mysql

Есть VPS 512, установлен LAMP, eAccelerator, в mysql использую конфиг medium + дописал это:

```
default-storage-engine = myisamskip-innodbskip-bdbskip-symbolic-linksskip-networkingskip-name-resolveskip-federatedskip-name-resolveskip-lockingread_buffer_size = 128Kread_rnd_buffer_size = 256Kjoin_buffer_size = 256Ksort_buffer_size = 128Kmyisam_sort_buffer_size=256M
```

Но ничего не помогает, память забивается и свободной остаётся очень мало.
Что мне делать в данной ситуации? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Вывод команды free покажите.

Comment: aza1io, http://rghost.ru/55886404/image.png

Comment: судя по картинке у вас все прекрасно с памятью.https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/chap-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Memory_Usage_and_Page_Cache.html

Comment: то есть у меня ещё куча свободной памяти и нужно обращаться внимание на строку buffers/cache?

Comment: вам стоит обращать внимание на free во второй строчке вывода команды free.

Comment: Универсальный совет: поставьте nginx перед apache, или вовсе откажитесь от apache. Голый apache на боевых серверах в принципе не стоит использовать.